# Fastest way to determine value based on boolean c++

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, integer, boolean

If you have a boolean `b` and an int `i`, which one of the two examples is better?

```
int x = i-1;
if(!b)x--;
```

or

```
int x;
if(b)x = i-1;else x = i-2;
```

In both examples if `b` is true `x` is `i-1`, else `x` is `i-2`. Should you declare `x` as `i-1` and decrement if `b` is false or should you use the second example?

Comment: The branchless version is `x = i - 2 + b;`

Comment: Chances are high that if you compile in release, the compiler would output the same code either way

Comment: Why do you even ask? Micro optimizations are irrelephant.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I was just curious.

Comment: @IvanRubinson micro optimizations are *often* irrelevant, but not always. I've worked on code where the inner loop was processed millions of times and only consisted of a couple of operations.

Comment: @MarkRansom `b` might not be a boolean.  Better to do `int const x = i - 1 - not b;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would be surprised if compilers didn't optimize both version to the same optimal assembly. Don't waste your time with this micro-optimizations unless you can prove that they are significant using a profiler.

To answer your question: it's irrelevant. Here's a "generated assembly" comparison on [gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/FjCZuE) with `-Ofast`.

---

```
volatile int state0;
volatile void f0(volatile int i, volatile bool b)
{
  int x;
  if(b)x = i-1;else x = i-2;
  state0 = x;
}
```

...gets compiled to...

```
f0(int, bool):                                # @f0(int, bool)
        mov     dword ptr [rsp - 4], edi
        mov     byte ptr [rsp - 5], sil
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rsp - 5]
        or      eax, -2
        add     eax, dword ptr [rsp - 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rip + state0], eax
        ret
```

---

```
volatile int state1;
volatile void f1(volatile int i, volatile bool b)
{
  int x = i-1;
  if(!b)x--;
  state1 = x;
}
```

...gets compiled to...

```
f1(int, bool):                                # @f1(int, bool)
        mov     dword ptr [rsp - 4], edi
        mov     byte ptr [rsp - 5], sil
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp - 4]
        movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rsp - 5]
        or      ecx, -2
        add     ecx, eax
        mov     dword ptr [rip + state1], ecx
        ret
```

---

As you can see, the difference is minimal, and is extremely likely to disappear when the compiler is allowed to optimize more aggressively by removing `volatile`.

---

Here's a similar comparison in picture form, using `-Ofast -march=native -ffast-math`:

[image: Godbolt comparison]

Comment: Please mention which flags you used (-O3?)

Comment: @IvanRubinson: it's on the godbolt link, I used `-Ofast`.

Comment: Thanks! I was asking just because I was curious.

Comment: @theo2003: you're welcome. Don't forget [to accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

Check the assembly code, since the optimizer will optimize, possibly both your solutions to the same solution.

I would probably implement it as:

```
int x = (b) ? i - 1 : i - 2;
```

For readability and high likely the optimizer will make it equal as your second solution.

Comment: I would write `int x = i - b ? 1 : 2;` not to mention `i` twice

Comment: I would write `const int x = i - 2 + !!b` so as not to have any branching at all.

Comment: Possibly or (int) b to make it more clear, but I learnt not to rely on int/bool casts; maybe some clint checking is done prohibiting the feature.